# XSLT web parts functioning after migrating to SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, xslt, upgrade, migrate

We are in the process of migrating and upgrading a client's SharePoint 2010 Intranet portal to SharePoint 2013. Our client has many custom web parts built in XSLT. These are basically Content Query Web Part running with custom XSL code. Would these web parts run after migration/upgrade?

Comment: They should in theory, but you should test to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Even the XSLT feature deprecated in SharePoint 2013 but still has Backward compatibility.
But your testing will prove it.

[Check this post for more information](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a72fdf95-24cf-46a7-b971-a3235340c3bf/xslt-in-sharepoint-2013)

Answer (score -1):

The use of `XSLT` has been replaced by Display Templates in SharePoint 2013. This means almost all your **branded Web Parts**, **Content Query styles** will no longer work after migrating to SharePoint 2013.